# PHP: Stripe connect API would not accept card details?

Tags: php, stripe-connect

I know that asking this here could be throwing a stone in the dark because I found 2 other similar questions but none had any answers to it.

Any way, I hope someone has already found the solution for this and can shed a light on it.

Let me explain the scenario first as it might help with finding a solution:

I am creating stripe `custom connect accounts` like this:

```
$acct = \Stripe\Account::create(array(
    "country" => "US",
    "type" => "custom",
    "email" => "email@mail.com"
));
```

Then I add `Bank Accounts` to them like so:

```
$account->external_accounts->create(
array(
        'external_account' => array(
            "object" => "bank_account",
            "country" => "US",
            "currency" => "usd",
            "account_holder_name" => 'Jane Austen',
            "account_holder_type" => 'individual',
            "routing_number" => "111000025",
            "account_number" => "000123456789"
        )
));
```

This all works fine so far....

Now, what I need to do is to be able to transfer Money/Payments from the *connected custom accounts* into their *Bank accounts*.

For that purpose, I will need to add a Credit Card to that `connetced account` so that card details can be used for making payments into the Bank Accounts.

So I went ahead and tried this:

```
$account->external_accounts->create(
array(
        'external_account' => array(
            "object" => "card",
            "exp_month" => 8,
            "exp_year" => 2018,
            "number" => "4012888888881881",
            "currency" => "usd",
            "cvc" => "123"
        )
));
```

And that did NOT work and gave me this error:

```
Requests made on behalf of a connected account must use card tokens from Stripe.js, but card details were directly provided.
```

So I changed my strategy and tried this:

```
$result = \Stripe\Token::create(
                    array(
                        "card" => array(
                        "name" => "Some Name",
                        "exp_month" => 8,
                        "exp_year" => 2018,
                        "number" => "4012888888881881",
                        "currency" => "usd",
                        "cvc" => "123"
                        )
                    ));



$token = $result['id'];


$account->external_accounts->create(
array(
        'external_account' => array(
            "object" => "card",
            "source" => "".$token.""
        )
));
```

However, this gave me the same error message!!!

This is very frustrating because if you look at their own API documentation, you will clearly see that they say:

```
source required

Either a token, like the ones returned by Stripe.js, or a dictionary containing a user's credit card details (with the options shown below). Stripe will automatically validate the card.
```

*This can be seen here:*

https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card

Could someone please advice on this issue?

I cannot use stripe.js in my project so I will need to use the API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**First Edit:**

Here is a strange one.. I generated a Stripe card token from here:

https://codepen.io/fmartingr/pen/pGfhy

Note that the above codepen uses the stripe.js to generate the tokens....

and tried to use the token from there in my PHP code like so:

```
$account->external_accounts->create(
array(
        'external_account' => array(
            "object" => "card",
            "source" => "tok_1AqPXeDQzcw33c71uncYBFdm"
        )
));
```

but this gives me the exact same error:

```
Requests made on behalf of a connected account must use card tokens from Stripe.js, but card details were directly provided.
```

Comment: How are you creating the token your sending as the source in the second attempt? Does the token get returned from stripe successfully?

Comment: @Birdy, my first attempt was using the `$result = \Stripe\Token::create(...)`. I have included the code in my question. Also, I have edited my question with another way of trying it (using stripe.js) generated token and used that token directly in the source but that gave me the same error message.

Comment: @Birdy, yes, I get the token successfully.

Comment: I can simply `echo $token;` on my page and I see the token on my page.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this it will add your external account

```
$result = \Stripe\Token::create(
                array(
                    "card" => array(
                    "name" => "Some Name",
                    "exp_month" => 8,
                    "exp_year" => 2018,
                    "number" => "4012888888881881",
                    "currency" => "usd",
                    "cvc" => "123"
                    )
                ));



$token = $result['id'];

$account->external_accounts->create(
   array(
      'external_account' => "".$token.""
));
```